# Dropwizard FileNotFoundException whilst the file is present and seen by debugger

Tags: java, rest, jersey, dropwizard

I am testing my endpoint built with dropwizard, but something goes wrong:

```
@Test
public void testPostWithFileSuccess() throws Exception
{
    FileDataBodyPart filePart = new FileDataBodyPart("file", new File(fixture("resources/testImage.jpg")));
    filePart.setContentDisposition(FormDataContentDisposition.name("file").fileName("testImage.jpg").build());

    FormDataMultiPart request = new FormDataMultiPart();
    request.field("data", fixture("resources/postWithFileSuccess.json"), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
    request.bodyPart(filePart);

    WebTarget target = mClient.target("http://localhost:8080/crackers").register(MultiPartFeature.class);
    Response response = target
            .request()
            .post(Entity.entity(request, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA));

    assertThat(response.getStatus()).isEqualTo(200);
}
```

What actually happens is the test fails on `.post(Entity.entity(request, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA));` with the following expection:

> javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Invalid file path
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:287)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:252)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:684)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:681)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:681)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:437)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:343)
>       at org.example.project.resources.CrackersTest.testPostWithFileSuccess(CrackersTest.java:201)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
>       at org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:48)
>       at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
>       at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
>       at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
>       at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
>   Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Invalid file path
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:133)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.FileProvider.writeTo(FileProvider.java:115)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.FileProvider.writeTo(FileProvider.java:67)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.MultiPartWriter.writeTo(MultiPartWriter.java:232)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.MultiPartWriter.writeTo(MultiPartWriter.java:79)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.invokeWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:265)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:250)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1130)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.doWriteEntity(ClientRequest.java:517)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.writeEntity(ClientRequest.java:499)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:388)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:285)
>       ... 42 more

I'm not completely sure, as if the file was not present or the path would have been wrong, an `Exception` would have been thrown on `new File(...)` declaration.

There is obviously something wrong with `filePart`, but what? If I comment `request.bodyPart(filePart);` out, the test just fails with a comparison error (that's expected).

Comment: Could you add your fixture method? I have a working unit integration test for that here, however I am using a stream. From your file address it seems like you should also use a stream?

Comment: @pandaadb Your comment just led me straight to the answer. Thanx!

Comment: That's great to hear. Maybe you can answer your own questions so others can learn as well. Also I am interested to know what was wrong :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `fixture(...)` method returns `Resources.toString(Resources.getResource(filename), charset).trim()`, hence debugger sees the file, but `post(...)` can't process it.

To fix the issue, instead of

```
new File(fixture("resources/testImage.jpg"))
```

I should have used

```
new File(Resources.getResource("resources/testImage.jpg").toURI())
```

Complete fixed method listing:

```
@Test
public void testPostWithFileSuccess() throws Exception
{
    FileDataBodyPart filePart = new FileDataBodyPart("file", new File(Resources.getResource("resources/testImage.jpg").toURI()));
    filePart.setContentDisposition(FormDataContentDisposition.name("file").fileName("testImage.jpg").build());

    FormDataMultiPart request = new FormDataMultiPart();
    request.field("data", fixture("resources/postWithFileSuccess.json"), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
    request.bodyPart(filePart);

    WebTarget target = mClient.target("http://localhost:8080/crackers").register(MultiPartFeature.class);
    Response response = target
            .request()
            .post(Entity.entity(request, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA));

    assertThat(response.getStatus()).isEqualTo(200);
}
```